# Turn recursion into loop

Tags: c++, recursion, optimization

I have an unknown type `T` that might be non-copy- or move-assignable, a function `T op(const T &foo, Other bar)` that computes and returns a new `T` based on an existing one, and a recursive function:

```
template<typename Iter, typename T>
T foldLeft(Iter first, Iter last, const T &z, std::function<T(T, Other)> op)
{
    if (first == last) {
        return z;
    }
    return foldLeft(std::next(first), last, op(z, *first), op);
}
```

The compiler can't always optimize the tail call, because `T` might have a non-trivial destructor. I'm trying to manually rewrite it with a loop, but can't figure out how to reassign to `z`.

Comment: If you are returning a `T`, then it must be copy or move constructible, so why would it not be copy or move assignable? I guess you will need to create a new object each time, maybe dynamically allocating it?

Comment: Like when `T` is `std::unique_ptr<int>`...? I want to do it on stack though, for better performance.

Comment: it's better to use an extra `typename Fun` template parameter instead of explicitly using `std::fuction`. That way, also regular functions and lambdas will work.

Comment: @TemplateRex Thanks, that's how I'm actually doing it. Here it's just a simplification.

Comment: You *can* explicitly `new`/`delete` into a buffer you provide, that could live on the stack, with `char buffer[sizeof(T)];`, but it'd be nasty. If you require copy construction, can you *really* not require copy assignment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may do the following, but the restriction is strange, and using `std::accumulate` seems simpler

```
template<typename Iter, typename T, typename Fn>
T foldLeft(Iter first, Iter last, const T &z, Fn op)
{
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof (T), alignof (T)> buf;
    T* res = new (&buf) T(z);
    for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it) {
        auto&& res2 = op(res, it);
        res->~T();
        res = new (&buf) T(std::move(res2));
    }
    T final_res = *res;
    res->~T();
    return final_res;
}
```

Note that it is not exception safe.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks! I need to roll my own version of `std::accumulate` because it requires the initial value to be both `CopyAssignable` and `CopyConstructible`, which makes folding over something like a `std::unique_ptr` impossible.

Comment: If you work with `std::unique_ptr`, using move assign would be simpler.